# how can i write an array of structures to a binary file and read it again?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, struct

I'm writing an array af structures(factor is a structure) to a binary file like this:

```
factor factors[100];

ofstream fa("Desktop:\\fa.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
fa.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&factors),sizeof(factors));

fa.close();
```

and I run the program and save 5 records in it.in another file, I want to read the structures so I wrote this:

```
    int i=0;
ifstream a("Desktop:\\fa.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);

factor undelivered_Factors[100];

    while(a && !a.eof()){
        a.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&undelivered_Factors),sizeof(undelivered_Factors));
        cout<<undelivered_Factors[i].ID<<"\t"<<undelivered_Factors[i].total_price<<endl;
        i++;
    }
    a.close();
```

but after reading and printing the saved factors it inly reads and shows the firs 2 of them in the array.why?what should i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Try just calling `read()` once.

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter of ofstream::write and ::read is size of written  memory in *bytes* (aka 'char' in C\C++), which is right - you're  writing entire array at once. In reading procedure you had mixed up an per element and array processing. You *expect* to read whole array, then you print one value, then you read another 100 of records which you do not have in file, I presume. also eof() happens only when you attempt to read and it failed. If you stand on end of file,eof() isn't triggered, that's why you get two records printed.

Comment: and what should I do to read only the recorded ones in array?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing complete read in the single call so your loop runs only one time hence it will output only first struct value. Change your while loop like this:

```
if(a)
{
   a.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&undelivered_Factors),sizeof(undelivered_Factors));
}
for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
{
   cout<<undelivered_Factors[i].ID<<"\t"<<undelivered_Factors[i].total_price<<endl;
}
```